# OWIN Katana vs Node.js performance benchmark

Tags: node.js, owin, katana

Which is the reliable performance benchmark of OWIN Katana and Node.js?
I am really interested in everything that has been tested and tried with Katana.

Comment: Really? No one has ever wondered about that?! ...

Comment: I am also searching for one such benchmark.. if you find one please share..

Comment: ASP.NET vNext supports self hosting out the box, writing a simple comparison with the demo "Hello World" app could be interesting and fairly easy.

Comment: Did anyone ever find anything regarding this?

Answer (score 1):

[Haney](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2420979/haney) did [some research](http://www.haneycodes.net/to-node-js-or-not-to-node-js/) on that, you may find it useful:

[image]